# Verificar Registro Al Hacer Un UPDATE PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Tengo El Siguiente Codigo Que se Supone Que Tiene Que Verificar Si Es Que Hay Un Regitro En Una BD El Problema Es Que No Verifica Si Existe El Registro

```html
<?php

include "../Funciones/Conexion.php";
$mysqli = inicio();


$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$fecha = date('Y-m-d');  
$horaS = date('g:i:s');


$sql = "UPDATE chequeo 
SET horaS = '$horaS' 
WHERE fecha = '$fecha'";

$verificar_hora = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM chequeo WHERE horaS = '$horaS'");
if (mysqli_affected_rows($verificar_hora) > 0 ){
 echo '<script>jQuery(function(){swal({
title:"Error",text:"Ya Checaste tu Dia De Salida, No Puedes Volver a Checar",type:"error",confirmButtonText:"Aceptar"
},function(){location.href="../Usuario.php";});});</script>';
 exit;
}


$query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
if ($query){
echo '<script>jQuery(function(){swal({
title:"Exito",text:"Has Checado Con Exito",type:"success",confirmButtonText:"Aceptar"
},function(){location.href="../Usuario.php";});});</script>';
}else{
echo '<script>jQuery(function(){swal({
title:"Error",text:"Ocurrrio Un Error Al Checar",type:"error",confirmButtonText:"Aceptar"
},function(){location.href="../Usuario.php";});});</script>';
}
?>
```

Espero Y Puedan Ayudarme

Comment: Tu código tiene varios problemas: **no es seguro**, no usa consultas preparadas; hacer un **`SELECT * ...`** sólo para verificar si se cumple el criterio de la hora no tiene sentido, ¡estás seleccionando todas las columnas de la tabla!; el mismo criterio de ese `SELECT` tiene poco sentido, si se trata de una tabla con varios usuarios, seleccionará la hora de cualquiera de ellos;  define variables que quizá nunca se usarán, como el caso del `$sql` para el `UPDATE`... un código óptimo controlaría el flujo en base a los `if...` sin tener que usar `exit` y creando variables cuando se necesiten.

Answer (score 0):

Hola iBokii verifica que tipo de dato tiene el campo horas en tu base de datos, y si acaso es igual al formato que envías:

> $horaS = date('g:i:s');

en tu base de datos debe tener ese mismo formato, caso contrario no encontrara ni un registro.

Comment: Pues El Formato Que Tengo En Mi BD Es De Tipo "Time"

Comment: Ya vi tu problema el tipo de dato Time el formato es 00:00:00 mientras que date('g:i:s') tiene un formato de 12 horas sin ceros, debes colocar esto date('h:i:s'); para que sea de 12 con ceros y ahi te funcionara tu consulta

Comment: verifica si tu formato es de 12 horas o 24 horas si es de 24 horas deberás colocar date('H:i:s'), puedes consultar aquí http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php